# Can't merge an NTFS partition and two unallocated spaces before and after it (using GParted)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I have 1 NTFS partition among others and two unallocated spaces: one before and one after it. I would like to merge all them together but GParted doesn't allow me to do this ("Resize/Move" is disabled). I also cannot create additional partition(s) because I already have 4 primary.

How can I do what I need?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition is mounted - it has a mount point (4th column) and a key symbol. Mounted partitions can't be manipulated because the filesystem can be accessed by other programs.

You can unmount it by right-clicking it in GParted and selecting *Unmount*.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now :)